# show 1 more comment but no more comments exist

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I was looking at a question and at the bottom of the comments there was a link that said

```
show 1 more comment
```

However, when I click on it, no other comment is shown. Once I click on it, the link disappears, but every time I refresh the screen, it re-appears.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Incidentally, the last comment happens to be mine. Not sure if this is unique to me or this situation, but thought I'd bring it up.

Link: [Why did Jesus use a Greek proverb when He spoke Aramaic to Saul in Acts 26:14?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40726/why-did-jesus-use-a-greek-proverb-when-he-spoke-aramaic-to-saul-in-acts-2614)

Just in case this is only appearing for me since it's under my comment, here is a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image]

Comment: Can you point us to the post where this is happening?

Comment: Yes, just edited my question.

Comment: Also added an image of what I'm seeing because I suspect it only happens when the last comment is by the person viewing the post.

Comment: The one comment hidden there is by fredsbend, immediately before yours. What happens if you click this direct link to said comment? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40726/why-did-jesus-use-a-greek-proverb-when-he-spoke-aramaic-to-saul-in-acts-2614#comment111707_40736

Comment: @El'endiaStarman OK. I see it now. I think I expected that the comment that was hidden was AFTER the last one showing, not one immediately before it. Why is it that way?

Comment: SE's system uses a combination of date/time posted *and* score to determine which comments to show, so your upvoted comment outranked fredsbend's.

Comment: OK. I didn't know that. Thanks for your time with this post. Should I delete this post or leave it?

Comment: @MattCremeens: I think there's no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being thrown off by the fact that the comments are prioritized. If it runs out of room to show all the comments, the system tries to keep a couple of the most highly voted comments. In many cases that means that the comments that get hidden are not the *latest* comments, they might be interspersed in the rest. Since the last comment in that set is upvoted, it opted to hide one of the earlier comments with no votes on it instead.

This is one thing to think about when voting on comments: vote up the comments that are most likely to be useful to other visitors in the event they don't read or even see them all.